# Replicate the share email to microsoft teams function

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-teams

I am currently investigating a way to share emails from our desktop application. Written in c# using .Net framework 4.7

We would like to use the same dialog that gets initiated when you use the "Share to Teams" button in outlook passing in the .eml file. The user would be responsible for selecting which people or channels to share to.

[image: Share Button Example]

[image: Share Dialog]

Does anyone have any recommendations?

We can succesfully build a simple url share using their launcher concepts, but this is pretty limited to the browser and doesn't support files
https://teams.microsoft.com/share?href=www.stackoverflow.com&msgText=Testing
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/share-to-teams

And there is nothing mentioned in their deep-links section on msdn to achieve this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're building your own desktop app experience anyway, why not use Graph for this? For instance, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http . You'd need to do your own Search box, but you can do that on Graph also - here for instance is a channel listing endpoint (this example is for within a specific Team): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Rob, did this help you? Were you able to make some progress?

Comment: Hi Hilton, we were hoping not to have to create our dialog but using Graph does look like the only solution at the moment.
I do have some experience with Graph and Emails so those links are a good starting point to achieve this.
Thanks for your input.

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful